# Meta-connect wall

Tags: connect-wall

Sort the sixteen words into four categories. The four categories are joined by a common thread, with that being the solution.

Text version below, or [play with a better UI](https://connections.swellgarfo.com/game/-NqaEExIEqLry-SqeVXh).

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HEAT TRANSFER | STOLEN BASE | BURNOUT | COMBAT TRAINING |
| BODY SPRAY | SWEAT | BISEXUAL | TOOTHPASTE |
| GETAWAY | AUTISTIC | CAT TOY | SIMPLE SYRUP |
| LIP BALM | INDIGO | HAT TRICK | MICROWAVE |

Answer (score 17):

Solved connections & meta-puzzle:

**#1**

> BODY SPRAY, TOOTHPASTE, SIMPLE SYRUP, LIP BALM: **MINT-flavoured things**

**#2**

> BISEXUAL, AUTISTIC, INDIGO, MICROWAVE: **things that belong on SPECTRUMs**

**#3**

> HEAT TRANSFER, COMBAT TRAINING, CAT TOY, HAT TRICK: **all contain the string "AT T" (AT&T)**

**#4**

> STOLEN BASE, BURNOUT, SWEAT, GETAWAY: **things that happen after a SPRINT**

**Meta-puzzle**

> MINT, SPECTRUM, AT&T, SPRINT: **they are all MOBILE corporations**!